# Copy Multiple Table Columns and Paste Values to New Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table where I need to copy/paste_values for two columns into two existing columns, so the formulas running in another column will have the correct returns.  I have the below code that I found online that allows me to copy and paste a single column, but I need to do multiple columns (they are adjacent).  So what I want to do is copy Columns H and I and pastes the vaules into J and K. I am a novice, so this is a struggle for me.  Any help would be appreciated.

```vb
Sub PasteValues()

    Dim H As String
    Dim I As String
    Dim J As String
    Dim K As String
    
    H = "Formula Start"
    I = "Formula Stop"
    J = "Shift Start"
    K = "Shift Stop"
    
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Activity_Report")
    
    Range("Activity_Report[" & H & "]").Copy
    Range("Activity_Report[" & J & "]").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Range("Activity_Report[" & I & "]").Copy
    Range("Activity_Report[" & K & "]").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.cutCoptyMode = False

End
```

Comment: Why not repeat the two copy/paste lines for the other columns?

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive the following error: runtime error 1004 : Method range of object - 'Global' failed. I am not sure how to correct.

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: The first added line when I copy and paste the range lines below the initial range lines. So the next .copy line.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using the tbl object directly and avoiding the copy/paste:

```vb
Dim tbl As ListObject
   
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    
tbl.ListColumns("Col3").DataBodyRange.Value = tbl.ListColumns("Col1").DataBodyRange.Value
tbl.ListColumns("Col4").DataBodyRange.Value = tbl.ListColumns("Col2").DataBodyRange.Value
```